# Como puedo personalizar los botones del evento window:beforeunload ANGULAR 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Trato de cambiar los botones del evento en angular, pero por default me viene el botón salir y cancelar, de hecho tambien quiero cambiar el mensaje del pop up y no me permite..

````
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) 
beforeunloadHandler(event) {
  console.log(event);

    this.userService.logout();
    localStorage.clear();
    console.log("Processing beforeunload..." );
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = 'TRATO DE CAMBIAR EL MENSAJE :( ';
    ```
````

Comment: El botón salir de donde? Cerrar la pestaña? Back?

Comment: sí, al cerrar la ventana del navegador..